# how to create redirects in apache2 htaccess basing on status code

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, apache2, http-status-code-404

I would like to know how to create redirects in htaccess for all status codes **except** errors *(404,503,etc.)* and serve a specific file **test.txt**

This is what I am trying but does not work. At the moment I am trying it with a 503 status code

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]

Redirect 503 /test.txt ???
ErrorDocument 503 /test.txt ???
```

Comment: Look for `ErrorDocument`

Comment: @anubhava please consider my updated question

Comment: `ErrorDocument` is to handle a specific status code. You cannot make it generic or conditional

Comment: Can I do `ErrorDocument 503 /test.txt` or `ErrorDocument 200 /test.txt` ?

Comment: Yes you can do `ErrorDocument 503 /test.txt` and 200 is not an error so no need to use `ErrorDocument` for that.

Comment: @anubhava what can I use for non error status codes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117455/discussion-between-neodev-and-anubhava).